# How can I access a scanner object (the user's input) in another class within the same package?

Tags: java, class, object, inheritance, java.util.scanner

I have read through the questions and answers related to this topic but have not have found the answer that I need, or maybe understand. I am new at programming and I am learning Java. I am trying to use the scanner object from my main public class in a sub class of the sub class of the main public class. I know that I can only extend one class out.

Can anyone try to help me understand how to access this scanner object (the user's input) in another class within the same package? I'm having trouble and this seems to be the only bug so far.

I keep getting the error "the value of the local variable 'total' is not used". I am not using it "locally" I suppose, meaning in the same class. I am trying to access it in the other class.

this is the scanner object in my main class:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double total = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter your total before tip: ");

    input.close();
```

Any ideas? I apologize if this is obvious, I can't seem to figure it out at this point.

Thank you for your time and assistance.

Comment: You don't need the `Scanner` (just the `total`), but if you need the `total` somewhere else - either store the value in a field, pass it to your other method, **or** just prompt for the input there.

Comment: Thank you, Elliot. I will research storing the value in a field and passing it to the other method. I think I may know how to do that already I am probably missing a small detail somewhere. Yes, I just need the total that was entered by the user to use in another class. At this point the other class does not recognize it.